# how to put white space before and after a character in text field

Tags: asp.net

how to put white space before and after a character in text field

eg Text="John"

so i need whit space before and after John

Comment: Can you post what you have tried and what is not working. Then we be able to figure out your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SomeField.Text = " " + SomeField.Text + " ";
```

or using [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
SomeField.Text = string.Format(" {0} ", SomeField.Text);
```

Comment: @user619642, maybe you could be a little more specific about this *not working*? What have you tried? What was the expected result? What was the actual result? If you got an exception obviously you should post the exception stacktrace, ... Remember that the more details you provide the better chances are of getting a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
string InputValue = " " + MyTextBox.Text + " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery, you could call this method...

```
function changeTxtBox(controlID) {
        var oldValue = $(controlID).val();
        var newValue = ' ' + result + ' ';
        $(controlID).val(newValue)
}
```